# Microsoft visual studio 2010

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010

I have a question about the two folders indicated in the image ( External dependencies and Ressource files ), What is the utility of these two folders, and what can be put inside them ?

in c programming example ?

[image]

Comment: Your title is way too vague, and this is something you could easily figure out by a quick google search.

Comment: I googled it , but unfortunantly no results about that

Comment: [Did you try hard enough?](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=visual+studio+resource+files%7Cfolder&spell=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the top of my head, external dependencies may include DLLs having an entry point, whereas resource file may include Dlls without entry point(resource DLL) or an image.

Comment: what is the difference between with/without entry point dll ? can the resource file contain a text file from which we want to read some data ?

Comment: A resource-only DLL is a DLL that contains nothing but resources, such as icons, bitmaps, strings, and dialog boxes-msdn and these Dlls should not have any entry point.
Whereas non-resource Dlls have a default DllMain function(which can be overridden) which called everytime Dll is loaded or unloaded in a thread or a process.
So in general your resource folder will include resources like icons or images or audio whereas external dependencies will include helper Dlls.
Refer msdn for more details on Dlls.